# Import Mongo Database to local meteor application

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've downloaded a backup of a Mongo database from a production application I have hosted on Mlab.com

I want to import that database to my local meteor application so I can test some changes to the architecture of the collections on the real application data without breaking the production app.

Is there a way to do this?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install Mongo locally on your machine to get the utilities you need, which is basically mongorestore. The command will look something like this:

```
sudo mongorestore --db newdb --drop /var/backups/mongobackups/01-20-16/newdb/
```

Meteor can connect to your database using this environment variable:

```
MONGO_URL=mongo://localhost:27017/newdb
```

There is an article about it for more detail here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-a-mongodb-database-on-ubuntu-14-04